# Change Color Theme of MS Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, colors, themes, color-theme

How can I change the color theme in Microsoft Outlook (or, even better, the whole of Windows 7) to a more readable theme such as [Solarized Dark](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in Outlook 2010 to change the color theme to the value other than Blue, Silver or Black: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Outlook-2010-color-scheme-66d5723d-6a0d-4579-838a-e2ce76634d1a

Comment: Well that's pretty disappointing. Hard to believe that in this day and age, they wouldn't put some kind of theming in there. Also this doesn't change the message text colours, which is the part that you're staring at the most!